# Library to integrate Google's OAuth/OpenID hybrid in Java Web App?

Tags: java, openid, oauth

I'm building a Java web app that needs access to a user's Google Calendar data - therefore I thought the OAuth/OpenID hybrid is the best way to go.

What's the best library to handle the job - and reduce the amount of code on my end?

I tried *openid4java* & *Spring Security OpenID* (both don't support hybrid) as well as *dyuproject* (couldn't get it integrated).

PS: GAE is not an option

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know any integrated library but I do it with an OpenID library ([openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/)), an OAuth library ([net.oauth Java implementation](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) [Edit: or [Scribe](http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)]) and my bare hands as follows:

My `OAuth consumer key` is like www.example.com so I use http://*.example.com as `OpenID realm`.

I add following parameters (to redirect url or form) when redirecting user to Google OpenID endpoint:

```
openid.ns.ext2=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
openid.ext2.consumer=<my oauth consumer key>
openid.ext2.scope=<oauth scope to be authorized>
```

In return in addition to plain OpenID response I receive:

```
openid.ext2.request_token=<request-token>
```

I exchange received request-token with access-token and access-secret which are what is needed to make OAuth-authorized calls. That's all!

Note that in plain OAuth along with request-token you have to use a request-secret and verifier but here you don't need them.

To have a better view you may read [Google OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html), [Google OpenID](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) and [OpenID OAuth Extension](http://step2.googlecode.com/svn/spec/openid_oauth_extension/latest/openid_oauth_extension.html).

Edit: [Here (comment 8)](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/issues/detail?id=110#c8) is the OAuth extension for openid4java that does above for you.

Comment: Great stuff John, That last line in "Note..." really saved my day. I had the request_token with me but had no idea how to get the access tokens! Now I know :)

Comment: So you don't need any form of signing? I'm struggling to implement this over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241094/openidoauth-for-youtube-using-openid4java), any chance you could take a look?

Answer (score 4):

It does not support OpenID but, [Scribe](http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) is a very good OAuth Java library that supports Google.

Comment: thanks for the tip - I'm now trying to use Spring Security OpenID (which itself uses openid4java) and Scribe together