# Google Federated Login (hybrid OpenID+OAuth) with wildcard realm

Tags: oauth, openid

I'm trying to implement Google's [OpenID+OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#oauth) protocol, and it doesn't work when openid.realm contains a wildcard:

```
openid.realm: http://*.example.com
openid.ns.oauth = http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
openid.oauth.consumer = www.example.com
openid.oauth.scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

The OpenID process works as expected, but the OAuth extension is silently ignored (no request_token in the response; no error either).

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#oauth) this seemed supported:

> Use the automated interface to register your domain, keeping in mind
>   that the registered domain must be consistent with the realm parameter
>   being used with OpenID. For example, the domain "www.somedomain.com"
>   is consistent with a realm of "http://*.somedomain.com".

It works with a realm of `http://www.example.com` (the callback receives a request_token parameter), however I can't change the realm since this would prevent existing users from signing in again.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The question is too vague.  What is the "it" that doesn't work?  What does work? What is the new thing you are trying to do? What domains are [registered with Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto)? How are you signing your requests?

Comment: updated: When setting the realm to `http://www.example.com` and `openid.oauth.consumer` to `www.example.com`, the callback receives a `request_token` as expected. When setting the realm to `http://*.example.com` and the consumer to either `www.example.com` or `example.com`, the callback doesn't receive a `request_token` (but the openid process succeeds).

Answer (score 0):

The `consumer` must be an actual domain name, not a wildcard.  Also, `*.example.com` specifies a subdomain of `example.com`; `example.com` is **not** consistent with `http://*.example.com`

The Goggle documentation is unclear, but you may need to [register your website with Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto) in order to use OpenID+OAuth with a wildcard domain.  As you can see, [JohnS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483728/johns) was able to get [OpenID+OAuth with a wildcard domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319375/712765) working with out any documented differences from your setup (other than using `ex2` instead of `ouath` as the namespace alias, but that shouldn't matter).

Comment: That's not what the documentation said: `the registered domain must be consistent with the realm parameter being used with OpenID. For example, the domain "www.somedomain.com" is consistent with a realm of "http://*.somedomain.com".`. This is exactly what i'm doing.

Comment: You said the `consumer` was `*.example.com`.  The `consumer` is not the `realm`.

Comment: oops! I meant "When setting the realm to `http://*.example.com` and the consumer to either **`www.example.com`** or `example.com`, the callback doesn't receive a `request_token` (but the openid process succeeds)".

Comment: OK, how about trying OAuth 2.0?

Comment: I would if I could, but the federated login protocol supports only oauth1, apparently (because google considers that oauth2 can be used for authentication too; and that if you use oauth2 you don't need openid). I have a user base signing-in with openid already, so I can't switch to oauth2.

Comment: You're right, my bad, you have to use OAuth 1 with Google's federated login.  Maybe you need to be registered with Google to use federated login with a wildcard realm?

Comment: So have you registered `www.example.com` with Google and then tried using that as the consumer? (As I said before, I would not expect `example.com` to work in any case.)

Comment: Yes, i've registered both `www.example.com` and `example.com`, and tried both as consumer.

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem is specifically regarding openid.realm with wildcard options:

## Authenticated realm.

**Identifies the domain that the end user is being asked to trust. (Example: "http://*.myexamplesite.com") This value must be consistent with the domain defined in openid.return_to**. If this parameter is not defined, Google will use the URL referenced in openid.return_to.

The value of realm is used on the Google Federated Login page to identify the requesting site to the user. It is also used to determine the value of the persistent user ID returned by Google.

**Note:** If you've been using both OpenID and OAuth separately, you may be able to use the ***same domain registration as long as the OpenID realm parameter value matches the OAuth consumer parameter value***. If the values don't match, either re-register a domain consistent with the OpenID realm value, or change the value of realm. However, changing the realm may not be a viable option if you have existing users with OpenID.

Another Important thing about **OAuth extension**:

***This is typically a DNS domain name. Must be consistent with the value for realm (for example, realm = example.com and ext2.consumer = "www.example.com", or realm = "http://****.***somedomain.com" and ext2.consumer = "www.somedomain.com").***

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what am I doing wrong, then?

Comment: seems yes I know, as I am also using Hybrid Login way but not the wildcard options but if you provide the exact script then help you better way with exact solution