# Intuit OpenId with wildcard realm?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid, intuit-partner-platform

I have implemeted a handler to use Intuit's OpenId and evertything is working fine, but now I would like to use same identifier for different subdomains. I have added a wildcard to the realm (http://*.example.com) according to [Google Federated Login (hybrid OpenID+OAuth) with wildcard realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666250/google-federated-login-hybrid-openidoauth-with-wildcard-realm)  but no luck.

Google Openid works fine with that realm but it doesn't seem to work for Intuit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Intuit's OpenId every subdomain gets a different identifier. This is to prevent alice.heroku.com from getting bob.heroku.com's openId identifier. Since these are sites controlled by different parties they should get unique identifiers.
Since you seem to control the top level domain, always trigger the openId from that domain to prevent getting different identifiers across subdomains.